How do I prove that $\sqrt[n+1]{ a \sqrt[n]{ a \sqrt[n-1]{ a } }}=a^{\frac{n}{n^{2}-1}}$?
So, in a problem that's on my textbook, I was asked to prove that:
$$\sqrt[n+1]{ a \sqrt[n]{ a \sqrt[n-1]{ a } }}=a^{\frac{n}{n^{2}-1}}$$
I have been working on this for slightly less than a week, giving it a try everyday, but haven't been able to solve it. I think I might be failing on something very simple and just can't see it, or I'm doing some calculations wrong due to distraction.
I've tried putting the $a$'s all inside one radical:
$$
\sqrt[n+1]{ a \sqrt[n]{ a \sqrt[n-1]{ a } }}=\sqrt[n+1]{ a \sqrt[n]{ \sqrt[n-1]{ a \times a^{n-1}} }}=\sqrt[n+1]{ a \sqrt[n^{2}-n]{ a\times a^{n-1} } }=\sqrt[ n+1]{ \sqrt[n^{2}-n]{ a\times a^{n-1} \times a^{n^{2}-n}} }
$$
$$
\iff \sqrt[n+1]{ a \sqrt[n]{ a \sqrt[n-1]{ a } }}=\sqrt[n^{3}-n]{ a\times a^{n-1} \times a^{n^{2}-n} }=\sqrt[n^{3}-n]{ a^{n^{2}} }=a^{\frac{n^{2}}{n^{3}-n}}
$$
But $a^{\frac{n^{2}}{n^{3}-n}}\neq a^{\frac{n}{n^{2}-1}}$
I've also tried converting every radical into a power with a fractional exponent and was unsuccesseful on resolving this problem. (I could write out all of my attempts but it would be A LOT of LaTeX code. If you really need all those other attempts written out, comment it and I'll do it).
So, how can I prove that $\sqrt[n+1]{ a \sqrt[n]{ a \sqrt[n-1]{ a } }}=a^{\frac{n}{n^{2}-1}}$ ?
Could someone write a proof of it so that I can spot my mistakes?
Or, could you point out something I did wrong in the attempt I showed you.
Thank you.

I’m voting to close this question because it has a trivial answer.

Alternative approach:
Let
$$A = \sqrt[n+1]{ a \sqrt[n]{ a \sqrt[n-1]{ a } }}.$$
To simplify the analysis, I am going to assume that $~n~$ is an integer, which I suspect represents the problem composer's intent.
Suppose that $~a~$ is negative.  Then, $~(n-1)~$ must be odd, else $~\displaystyle \sqrt[n-1]{a}~$ is undefined.
This would imply that:

$n~$ is even.

$\displaystyle a \times \sqrt[n-1]{a}~$ is negative.


This would imply that $~\displaystyle \sqrt[n]{a ~\sqrt[n-1]{a}}~$ is undefined.
Therefore, $~a~$ can not be negative.

Further, the assertion is clearly true when $~a = 0.~$  Therefore, you can assume, without loss of generality that $~a > 0.$
When $~a \neq 0,~$ to the best of my knowledge, an expression like $~\displaystyle \sqrt[0]{a}~$ is undefined.
Therefore, each of the integers $~n, ~(n-1),~$ and $~(n+1)~$ can be assumed to not equal $~0.~$
This implies that $~A~$ is well defined and positive.

Therefore, in each of the following equations, each individual expression is well defined and positive.
Note that when (for example) $~R,S > 0,~$ and $~n \neq 0,~$ that
$~[ ~( ~R^n = S^n~) \iff ( ~R = S ~) ~].$

So
$$A^{n+1} = a \sqrt[n]{ a \sqrt[n-1]{ a } } \implies $$
$$A^{n+1} \times \frac{1}{a} = \sqrt[n]{ a \sqrt[n-1]{ a } } \implies $$
$$[ ~A^{n+1} ~]^n \times \frac{1}{a^n} =  a \sqrt[n-1]{ a } \implies $$
$$A^{(n+1) ~n} \times \frac{1}{a^{n+1}} = \sqrt[n-1]{ a } \implies $$
$$[ ~A^{(n+1) ~n} ~]^{n-1} \times \left[ ~\frac{1}{a^{n+1}} ~\right]^{n-1} = a \implies $$
$$A^{(n+1) ~n ~(n-1)} = a^{(n+1) ~(n-1)} \times a = a^{(n^2 - 1)} \times a = a^{[ ~n^2 ~]} \implies $$
$$\left[ ~A^{(n+1) ~(n-1)} ~\right]^n = \left[ ~a^n ~\right] ^n \implies $$
$$A^{(n+1) ~(n-1)} = a^n \implies $$
$$A = a^{\left[ ~\frac{n}{(n+1) ~(n-1)} ~\right]} = a^{\left[ ~\frac{n}{n^2 - 1} ~\right]}.$$

You can swap the order of the roots here:
$$\sqrt[n+1]{ a \sqrt[n]{ \sqrt[n-1]{ a \times a^{n-1}} }}$$
as
$$\sqrt[n]{ \sqrt[n-1]{ a \times a^{n-1}} }=\sqrt[n-1]{ \sqrt[n]{a^{n}} }=\sqrt[n-1]{a}$$
